# My random number generator does not create a new value in my loop C#

Tags: c#, .net, random

I am using c# to try and populate a datagridview with random numbers but for some reason I keep getting the same value in all the cells.

```
    public int GenerateRandomNumber()
    {
        const int minimumNumber = -9;
        const int maximumNumber = 15;
        var random = new Random();
        var randomNumber = random.Next(minimumNumber, maximumNumber);
        return randomNumber;
    }
```

gameBoard is the datagrid view.

```
    private void populateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateGameBoard((int)columnsNumericUpDown.Value,(int)rowsNumericUpDown.Value);
        gameBoard.RowTemplate.Height = gameBoard.Height/gameBoard.RowCount;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gameBoard.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {

                cell.Value = GenerateRandomNumber();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: See also: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx

Comment: You should use a different seed each call to this method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Random is initialized using the clock which means that you will get the same value multiple times.

So, instead of re-creating Random instance you should keep a single Random instance and keep using Next on the same instance. If you have multiple threads then you should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number) for locking solution

This is what you need.

```
private Random random = new Random();
const int minimumNumber = -9;
const int maximumNumber = 15;
public int GenerateRandomNumber()
{        
    var randomNumber = random.Next(minimumNumber, maximumNumber);
    return randomNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Do not *re-create* random generator:

```
// Random generator, one instance for the loop, no re-creation 
private m_Random = new Random();
...
public int GenerateRandomNumber()
{
    const int minimumNumber = -9;
    const int maximumNumber = 15;

    // Do not re-create random generator! Use single instance instead
    //var random = new Random();
    var randomNumber = m_Random.Next(minimumNumber, maximumNumber);
    return randomNumber;
}
```

Comment: This will not work properly in a multi-threaded environment, as `Random` is not thread-safe. You should *at least* mention this in the answer, even if you don't provide a thread-safe alternative.